# Where are up-to-date JavaScript-specific documentations and samples of NativeScript UI ListView?

Tags: telerik, nativescript, progress, nativescript-telerik-ui, nativescript-plugin

I couldn't find any up-to-date JavaScript-specific docs and samples of NativeScript UI ListView.
The official docs only uses TypeScript.

I found a blog on NativeScript UI components but they are old.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.nativescript.org/start/introduction) you find all the documents specific to {N} Core, if you don't find anything in particular, please be specific.

Comment: I need this doc but it is for TypeScript and I use vanilla JS https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/swipe-actions

Comment: Hi, where can I find an up to date JavaScript-specific (not typescript) doc or sample of NativeScript Pro UI ListView component (with swipe)? This official doc is only in TypeScript https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/Controls/NativeScript/ListView/swipe-actions

docs.telerik.com

RadListView Swipe Actions | Progress NativeScript UI Documentation

This article gives insight how the Swipe Actions feature is used.

Comment: If you remove typings from TypeScript, then it's just JavaScript. Or you could use a transpiler to quickly see how some code would look with JavaScript. In my humble opinion, it's hard to expect a JavaScript example everywhere while TypeScript is dominating today with it's benefits.

Comment: Do you mean if I remove the types it will work in my vanilla JS project?

Comment: Mostly, yes it would.

Comment: How can I mix TypeScript codes in my vanilla JS project?

Comment: Can I mix TS with my vanilla JS NS project?

Comment: No, Typescript can't be combined with JavaScript project.